# How to create a plugin page that shows XML?

Tags: plugins, admin, xml

I'm looking for the best way to create a plugin page that displays XML.

It needs to be:

- Front facing to the public
- Valid XML that removes all the admin hub-bub and allows me to change the header info
- Doesn't display in the side menu

Comment: If you could show us an example document, that might help. For example, display XML ... of what?  An XML-representation of a post/page?

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure how your "public" requirements combines with context of admin.

In general easiest way to create page with very customized markup is to use [custom named template](http://codex.wordpress.org/Pages#Creating_Your_Own_Page_Templates).